# Is SARIMAX a deterministic algorithm?

Tags: time-series

SARIMAX is a well-known algorithm for time series forecasting.
But I'm not sure if it is deterministic or non-deterministic.
Could you help me?

Comment: Non-deterministic as in deterministic differential equations. But one could make the model building reproducible.

Comment: @msuzen I'm not sure if I understood. Actually, I would like to know if SARIMAX has random components (as the random weights of neural networks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SARIMAX is first a *model*, which can then be used for forecasting, but also for other uses.

SARIMAX is completely deterministic in the usual implementations: if you run it multiple times with the same input, you will get the same output each time. (You could in principle use randomization in your search for AR and MA orders, but I don't know of anyone who advocates this.)